# Configuration of a JAR application

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I want to distribute my application like a JAR file and configurable by external files, so the final directory structure will looks like:

```
--conf
----log4j.properties
    ...
--lib
----log4j.jar
    ...
--myApp.jar
--run.bat
```

In the run.bat I start my application with:

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

In the MANIFEST.MF I have class-path entry:

```
Class-Path: conf/log4j.properties lib/log4j.jar
```

But the application is not able to locate its configuration files (but it is able to locate the libs!). What I am missing? Anyway is it a good practice to externalize configuration files to a folder which are relevant to the 'main' JAR?

EDIT:
My intention to externalize the configuration files is that in this way they can be edited more easily.
EDIT: config -> conf (typo in the description of the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath should be:

```
Class-Path: conf/ lib/log4j.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have your config files in the "conf" directory and your classpath is looking for a "config" directory? :)

Comment: Nope. I have a typo in the description, sorry. The issue still remains. Editing the post...

Comment: Oh well, if your typo had been in your file system or classpath and not in your answer, I'd have been right! :)